# Blender 2.82.7 - Animation sequence from images - how to reverse/backwards?

Tags: animation, video-sequence-editor

I know that I have created a video of images in Blender 2.8 beta and have been able to reverse the sequence of images with a checkbox called 'Reverse' or 'Backwards', now that I am at Blender 2.82.7 I simply cannot seem to figure out where this is.  I've checked all the different editor types, call menus, drop down menus etc - Did this feature get lost from the latest kit or has it moved or am I just a noob missing the obvious?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Finally found it, maybe this post will help someone else.
[image]